# How to add 'Play with VLC (no disc menus)' to context menu?

Tags: windows-explorer, vlc-media-player

I love VLC's 'no disc menus' feature to play DVDs.

How can I add a menu item 'Play with VLC (no disc menus)' to the context menu for DVDs in Windows Explorer?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the existing option by editing the registry entry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DVD\shell\PlayWithVLC\Command` and replacing `dvd://` with `dvdsimple://`

If you want to create a second menu option (instead of editing the first one), copy the `PlayWithVLC` key, give it another name (like `PlayWithVLCNoMenu`), modify the value inside to `Play with VLC (no disc menus)`, and then edit the `command` to use `simpledvd` instead of `dvd`.

Source:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Opening_a_DVD_or_VCD.2C_or_an_audio_CD.

Answer (score 2):

Registry entry based on Moshe's answer

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DVD\shell\PlayWithVLCNoDiscMenus]
@="Play with VLC media player (no disc menus)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DVD\shell\PlayWithVLCNoDiscMenus\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" --started-from-file dvdsimple:///%1"
```